# Docker - Two containers on same network can't connect over web socket

Tags: docker, networking, containers, crossbar, wamp-protocol

## Disclaimer

**This is only happening on my machine. I tested the exact same code and procedure on my colleague's machine and it's working fine.**

## Problem

Hello, I have a fairly weird problem at hand.

I am running two Docker containers: One is a [crossbar](https://crossbar.io/docs/Getting-Started/) server instance, and the other is an application that uses WAMP (Web Application Messaging Protocol) and registers to the running crossbar server. 
Nothing crazy

I run these two applications on two different docker containers that share the same network.

```
docker network create poc-bridge
docker run --net=poc-bridge -d --name cross my-crossbar-image
docker run --net=poc-bridge --name app my-app-image
```

Here is the dockerfile I used to build the image `my-crossbar-image`

```
FROM crossbario/crossbar

EXPOSE 8080

USER root
COPY deployment/crossbar/.crossbar /node/.crossbar
```

It simply exposes the port and copy some config files.

The other image for the app that needs to register to the crossbar server is not relevant.

Once I run my app in its container and it tries to register something to the crossbar server using the websocket address `ws://cross:8080/ws` I get: 
 `OSError: [Errno 113] Connect call failed ('172.24.0.2', 8080)`

## What I tried

- I checked that the two containers are actually on the same network (they are)
- I could ping container `cross` from my container `app` with `docker exec app ping cross -c2` (weird)

What can it be???

Comment: Is the process inside the server container actually listening on `0.0.0.0:8080`?  If the port number doesn't match, or if the container is only listening on the container-private localhost interface `127.0.0.1`, you'll get a "connection refused" error.

Comment: But why would it work on another machine then?

Comment: And also, how come I can ping it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem was not clear. However, it disappeared. All I had to do was:

- Stopping/Removing all the created containers
- Removing all the created images
- Removing all the created networks
- Re-building all again

Now the services can communicate to each other